# Plot deformed 2D mesh with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a deformed rectangular mesh, which means that the coordinates of the nodes depend on the indices of the node. The purpose is to visualize the deformation of unit square by a function.

How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 7):

This is the type of thing that `pcolormesh` (or `pcolor`) is meant for.  (Also have a look at `triplot`, etc for triangular meshes.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y, x = np.mgrid[:10, :10]
z = np.random.random(x.shape)

xdef, ydef = x**2, y**2 + x

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
axes[0].pcolormesh(x, y, z, cmap='gist_earth')
axes[1].pcolormesh(xdef, ydef, z, cmap='gist_earth')

axes[0].set(title='Original', xticks=[], yticks=[])
axes[1].set(title='Deformed', xticks=[], yticks=[])

plt.show()
```

[image]

On a side note, `pcolormesh` defaults to using no antialiasing for performance reasons.  If you add `antiailiased=True` to the `pcolormesh` call, you'll get a nicer-looking result:

[image]